# HTML slight margin issue

Tags: html, css

So I am new to web development and was trying to practice by making a portfolio for myself but I ran into a slight issue. It seems that when a set margin-top to a divider, my navigation bar shifts a bit to the right.

So for some reason, when I apply "`margin-top: 300px;`" to the "`.header`" class, my navigation bar shifts to the right a bit.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', 'sans-serif';
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-padding-top: 1rem;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-header {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav-header h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--text-highlight)
}

nav ul li a:active {
  color: var(--text-active);
}

nav ul li a span {
  color: var(--text-active);
}

:root {
  --text-color: #000000;
  --text-highlight: #D3D3D3;
  --text-active: #6b84d1;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
  ;
}

.header h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 100, 0);
  font-size: 64px;
}

.header p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.header hr {
  margin-top: 225px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Kelvin Kuoch | Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d4a6ce6cea.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function scrollToTop() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a class="nav-header">
        <h2 onclick="scrollToTop()">Kelvin Kuoch</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a><span onclick="scrollToTop()" class="homeBtn">Home</a></span>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#my-work">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr id="nav-div">
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <h2>I'm Kelvin, a <br> highschool student <br> based in Australia.</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-container" id="my-work">
      <h1>My Work</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you mean it shifts to the left (instead of right) and that is due to the scroll bar appearing when the content overflows the page

Comment: <li><a><span onclick="scrollToTop()" class="homeBtn">Home</a></span></li> tags are not closed properly it must be like <li><a><span onclick="scrollToTop()" class="homeBtn">Home</span></a></li>

Comment: It's the scrollbar. You can see the same thing happen simply by resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your `.navbar` class; when I remove the  extra margin it showing well:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Before removing the margin:
[image]

After removing it is fine now:
[image]

But I suggest you to use [Bootstrap navigation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) which are fully responsive.

Comment: You should use the editor to create a demo snippet. Screenshots aren't ideal.